# network - disableEditMode on click

Tags: vis.js-network

When double-clicking on an edge or a node I enter the edit or add mode, then I can do the modification. This works fine:

```
network.on("doubleClick",function(params) {                                                                                                                                               
    console.log(params);                                                                                                                                                                  
    if ( (params.edges.length > 0) && (params.nodes.length == 0) ) {                                                                                                                      
        network.editEdgeMode();                                                                                                                                                           
    } else if (params.nodes.length > 0) {                                                                                                                                                 
        network.addEdgeMode();
    }                                                                                                                                                                                     
});
```

I would like to get out of the mode when the user clicks elsewhere, for that I tried to use the click event in combination with `disableEditMode()` but this does not seem to work:

```
network.on("click",function(params) {
    console.log(params);
    network.disableEditMode();
});
```

Is this actually possible? Is this the purpose the `disableEditMode()` is made for?

Comment: So the first part works as expected even though you have 2 `addEdgeMode`, not `addEdgeMode` and `addNodeMode`? More related to the issue: do you click elsewhere *in the canvas* or out of it?

Comment: yes the first part works as expected : when double-clicking on the node, I draw an edge to another node (= addEdgeMode) ; when double-clicking on an edge, I update it by dragging it to another mode. I click inside the canvas. if it is not possible, maybe bind the escape key to disableEditNode() ?

Comment: Looks like `disableEditMode()` works ok, but in the edit edge mode the `click` event of vis.js is not fired